# Replacing RPATH when Deploying Qt Shared Libraries

Tags: qt, makefile, qmake, dynamic-linking

### Setup

- I have a local installation of Qt located in my home directory: `/home/user/Qt/...` (from now on, *devdir*).
- The Qt application that I'm trying to package installs the relevant Qt shared libraries to `/usr/lib/myapplication` (from now on, *installdir*).
- My packaging process is currently set up like this:

  `qmake` > `dh_make -s --createorig` > `debuild`

### Problem

I am trying to set `RPATH` in *myapplication.pro* to only link to libraries in *installdir*, but it is currently linking to both *installdir* and *devdir*.

I think it has to do with `qmake` creating dependencies to the installation libraries automatically. To try to stop it, I have run the build process with `qmake -nodepend`, but that hasn't stopped the link to *devdir* from happening.

How do I force `qmake` to link only to libraries in *installdir*?

### Code

In *myapplication.pro*:

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS = -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/myapplication
```

The resulting link flags in the Makefile are:

```
LFLAGS = -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/myapplication -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-rpath,/home/user/Qt/5.3/gcc_64 -Wl,-rpath,/home/user/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/lib
```

Comment: AFAIK, `RPATH` plays a role in determining which libraries to load at _runtime_. Perhaps it's `LIBPATH` (i.e. `-Linstalldir`) what you should touch...?

Comment: @Kalrish From what I understand, `LIBPATH` links to libraries while building, which is fine since _devdir_ is what I am using to build the project. Changing it would be OK if I only had static libraries. It is `RPATH` that determines where the application will look for shared libraries when executing on another system - so it is `RPATH` that I want to tell to only look in _installdir_.

Comment: Then, it seems you need to set `RPATH` to both _devdir_ and _installdir_: the former for development, the later when shipping the program. See [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/22999/54084). By the way, I believe that `RPATH` is deprecated and `RUNPATH` is preferred.

Comment: @Kalrish Yes, exactly what I was thinking. I am now at the shipping stage and would like to set `RUNPATH` so that it links only to _installdir_. It is currently linking to both, with the _devdir_ being linked by qmake automatically. I want to stop it from doing that, else I will have to constantly `chrpath` after building. Perhaps the original phrasing of the question wasn't clear?

Comment: Although I don't know qmake, he right variables seem to be (`QMAKE_LIBDIR`)[http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html#qmake-libdir] (library directories to search libraries in at link-time) and (`QMAKE_RPATHDIR`)[http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html#qmake-rpathdir] (you are using Qt 4.8, right?). You could use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` during development, setting `QMAKE_LIBDIR` to _devdir_ and `QMAKE_RPATHDIR` to _installdir_ (if it isn't in the default directories of your distribution by default; those settings, after all, are per-distro).

Answer (score 0):

The path to `/home/user/Qt/5.3/gcc_64` can be removed by overwriting `QMAKE_RPATHDIR`. To suppress both paths the variable `QMAKE_LFLAGS_RPATH` should be empty as in [Setting RPATH order in QMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27384406/setting-rpath-order-in-qmake/27393241#27393241)

```
# rpath variables for unix
unix: {
    # suppress the default RPATH
    QMAKE_LFLAGS_RPATH =
    # add custom path
    QMAKE_LFLAGS = -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/myapplication
}
```