# Setting RPATH order in QMake

Tags: linux, qt, qmake, rpath

I have a Linux Qt program. I'd like it to preferentially use the (dynamic) Qt libraries in the executable's directory if they exist, otherwise use the system's Qt libs. RPATH to the rescue.

I add this line to the **qmake**'s .pro file:

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS    += '-Wl,-rpath,\'\$$ORIGIN\''
```

and looking at the resulting executable with **readelf** I see:

```
0x000000000000000f (RPATH)              Library rpath: [$ORIGIN:/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-5.2.0/lib]
0x000000000000001d (RUNPATH)            Library runpath: [$ORIGIN:/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-5.2.0/lib]
```

Seems right, but **ldd** shows it's using the system version:

```
libQt5Core.so.5 => /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-5.2.0/lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007f2d2fe09000)
```

If I manually edit qmake's resulting Makefile to swap the order of the two rpaths, so $ORIGIN comes after /usr/local/..., I get the right behavior:

```
0x000000000000000f (RPATH)              Library rpath: [/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-5.2.0/lib:$ORIGIN]
0x000000000000001d (RUNPATH)            Library runpath: [/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-5.2.0/lib:$ORIGIN]

libQt5Core.so.5 => ./libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007fb92aba9000)
```

My problem is with how **qmake** constructs the final LFLAGS variable. I can't figure out how to make it put my addition ($ORIGIN) after the system library. Any ideas?

Comment: Why would you like to prefer local libraries over system libraries? In a usual deployment scenario where you ship libraries with the binary, you have local only or system over local.

Comment: I wouldn't do this for a production product, but it's useful for debugging, where the local library has some extra diagnostic output (for example). I realize I can just use something along the lines of LD_LIBRARY_PATH in a wrapper script, but I scurried down this QMAke / RPATH rabbit hole, and now I'm curious about how to make QMake do what I want...

Answer (score 15):

You can add the following to your .pro file to force the dynamic linker to look in the same directory as your Qt application at runtime in Linux :

```
unix:{
    # suppress the default RPATH if you wish
    QMAKE_LFLAGS_RPATH=
    # add your own with quoting gyrations to make sure $ORIGIN gets to the command line unexpanded
    QMAKE_LFLAGS += "-Wl,-rpath,\'\$$ORIGIN\'"
}
```

If you want it to look in a subdirectory of the executable path, you can use :

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS += "-Wl,-rpath,\'\$$ORIGIN/libs\'"
```

Note that you should have the .so files with the exact same name in your application directory. For example you should copy `libQt5Core.so.5.2.0` to your application directory  with the name `libQt5Core.so.5`. Now the ldd shows the directory of the application.

You can also have `libQt5Core.so.5.2.0` and a link to it with the name `libQt5Core.so.5` in the application directory.

Comment: This is close. Setting `QMAKE_FLAGS_RPATH=` to suppress the default was the key. Then I can do:    `QMAKE_FLAGS += "-Wl,-rpath,\'/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-5.2.0/libs\' -Wl,-rpath,\'\$$ORIGIN\'"` to get the right elements in RPATH in the right order. There's probably some variable that holds the system path I could use, but I couldn't find it...

Answer (score 1):

As far as my research can say, you can only add RPATH at the beginning of the list with QMake.

But if you are on Linux and can install `chrpath`, you can hack your way around that.

Add this block at the end of your .pro file

```
# Add spacing since chrpath cannot expand RPATH length
QMAKE_RPATHDIR = \
    /XYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXY1\
    /XYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXY2\
    /XYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXY3\
    /XYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXY4
QMAKE_POST_LINK += 'chrpath -r \'/my/qt/installation:\$$ORIGIN\' $$OUT_PWD/mybinaryname;'
```

Comment: Not quite the solution I was anticipating, but a great hack none the less!

Comment: One could use `patchelf --set-rpath` instead of `chrpath -r`. It seems it has no problem expanding the rpath as well, so no need to clear QMAKE_RPATHDIR.

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking a bit of a guess at what's happening, but it's based on knowing some of the odd behaviours of ld.

check for the presence of an `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable that will come into effect before the processing of a RUNPATH variable. Because of the presence of both `RPATH` and `RUNPATH`, the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` rule comes into effect, so if it's set then unset it.

Secondly, I'd never expect to see:

```
libQt5Core.so.5 => ./libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007fb92aba9000)
```

in the output of `ldd`, I would always see the expansion of `$ORIGIN` to the directory of the binary (maybe you shortened it?), so I would have expected:

```
libQt5Core.so.5 => /path/to/bin/./libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007fb92aba9000)
```

Which means it sounds like the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` expansion is `.:/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-5.2.0/lib`, which to me sounds like you've got environmental overrides happening.

Comment: That is the verbatim output from ldd, no shortening involved. LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not set in any of these examples.

Comment: Do you have *any* `LD_` environment variables set? do you get the same behaviour with `env -i ldd <program>`? What linux distro are you using (trying to check for bugs)?

Answer (score 0):

qmake would always append the `QMAKE_RPATHDIR` with the `QT_INSTALL_LIBS` internally defined in `$(QT_DIR)/mkspecs/features/qt.prf` file:

```
170:    relative_qt_rpath:!isEmpty(QMAKE_REL_RPATH_BASE):contains(INSTALLS, target):\
173:        QMAKE_RPATHDIR += $$relative_path($$[QT_INSTALL_LIBS], $$qtRelativeRPathBase())
175:        QMAKE_RPATHDIR += $$[QT_INSTALL_LIBS/dev]
179:!isEmpty(QMAKE_LFLAGS_RPATHLINK):!contains(QT_CONFIG, static) {
189:    QMAKE_RPATHLINKDIR *= $$unique(rpaths)
```

So to avoid your application using the `QT` **library from system path**, comment out the lines above which append the `QMAKE_RPATHDIR` and add `QMAKE_RPATHDIR=$ORIGIN` into your `.pro` file.